# DevOps pipeline: variable for Resource repository name

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml pipeline. I can access the name of the branch that the yaml is taken from using `Build.SourceBranchName`.

**How can I access the name of the branch containing the code being built?** In other words, the name of the branch the Resource is being taken from. In this example image, the value I want would be "*development*":

[image]

**Note**: The pipeline is not being triggered from a Pull Request, so I can't use `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available as a [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

You can retrieve it by calling the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the full details of the pipeline run:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

This will return details of all the resources in use by this pipeline, including the CMIS repository resource's repo and branch.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I'll try this out! <3

Comment: Hi @HelloWorld, how's things going. Does it work for you? If it helps, just a remind of [ accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @AntoniaWu-MSFT Hi!   Unfortunately the work his delayed because of higher priority things, so I haven't been able to try yet! :(.  Probably be another 1-2 weeks before I can try

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you come back from busy tasks, don't forget to try whether it works : )

Comment: I haven't managed to get it working yet but I can see the information I need in the JSON response body for the API so this is exactly what I was looking for :) I'll try bodge it with a shell script or something